# Undefined value upon conversion of data from redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, redis, promise

I'm using mongo tailable cursor, redis (to get the value of report_id) and socket io to send data to the socket client. One of my problem is the function `getIdent(rpt_id)` is not getting called upon the execution of the code and when I `console.log(live_reports)` the value of `report_id` is `undefined`. I'm not sure but I think this is due to a fast reading of data on mongodb and conversion of `rpt_id` on the fly.

Is there any solution on this? I've read promises but I don't know how to integrate it to my code. I'm not good on javascript programming, any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
var mdb_host = 'mongodb://localhost/reports';
var mdb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var http = require('http');
var socketPort = 8888;
var app = http.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

var redis = require('redis');
var redis_client = redis.createClient();

socket.on('connection', function(conn) {
    console.log(conn.id + ' connected');
});

mdb.connect(mdb_host, function(err, db) {
    if (!err) {
        db.collection('col_reports', function(err, col) {
            var cursor = col.find({}, {
                    tailable: true,
                    awaitdata: true
                }),
                cStream = cursor.stream();

            cStream.on('data', function(results) {

                var rpt_id = getIdent(results.ident);

                var live_reports = {
                    report_id: rpt_id,
                    timestamp: results.timestamp,
                    sender: {
                        country: results.country,
                        city: results.city
                    },
                    receiver: {
                        country: results.country,
                        city: results.city
                    },
                    delivery_type: results.del_type
                }

                io.emit('live reports', live_reports);
                io.emit(rpt_id, live_reports);
            });
        });
    }
});

app.listen(1234);

function getIdent(ident) {
    redis_client.get(ident, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            return data;
        } else {
            console.log('an error occurred: ' + err)
        }
    });
}
```